# Who knows yolov8 model's results mean?

Tags: yolo

I use yolo v8 recently,but I don't know what it's results means. 
It's output only 1 bbox and its likelihood,but I want get prediction of other categories.
Can you tell me more about this model?
if you know where can get documents about it, please tell me, thanks

[image].